# Prove independence of random variables in two independent vectors

Tags: probability

disclaimer: This is a homework problem.

Hello all,

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time. I am given $X = (X^1, X^2)$ and $Y = (Y^1, Y^2)$. $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X^1, X^2$ are independent and $Y^1, Y^2$ are independent.

The question is: Prove that $X^1, Y^2$ are independent.

So far, I know that $P(X, Y) = P(X^1)P(X^2)P(Y^1)P(Y^2)$ due to the independence of the vectors and the independence of elements within each vector. I am having trouble going from this to the independence of $X^1, Y^2$.

Right now, I am saying that $P(X, Y) = P(X^1, Y^2, X^2, Y^1) = P(X^1, Y^2)P(X^2, Y^1) = P(X^1)P(Y^2)P(X^1)P(Y^2)$ so $P(X^1, Y^2) = P(X^1)P(Y^2)$ thus they are independent. But I feel that this is not correct because I have not shown that $(X^1, Y^2)$ and $(X^2, Y^1)$ are independent.

Is anyone able to lead me in the right direction?

Thank you.

Comment: That X and Y are independent is enough to deduce that X^1 and Y^2 are.

Answer (score 0):

Since $X=(X_1,X_2)\perp Y=(Y_1,Y_2),\ \forall u=(u_1,u_2),\ v=(v_1,v_2),\ \Phi_{X,Y}(e^{j(u^TX+v^TY)})=\Phi_X(e^{ju^T X})\Phi_Y(e^{jv^TY})$. Now, put $u_2=0,v_1=0$ and then it follows that $\Phi_{X_1,Y_2}(e^{j(u_1X_1+v_2Y_2})=\Phi_{X_1}(e^{ju_1X_1})\Phi_{Y_2}(e^{jv_2Y_2})\implies X_1\perp Y_2$